# SQL How to take a list of items and create a new table based on date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping someone can help me with a query.  I'm quite a beginner and I'm not looking for someone to write code for me, as I'd rather learn how to do this, but I'm not sure how to word a search to help me do what I need to do, so if I can get pointers on the search parameters I should be using that would be great.

I have a table of data :

```
Room Number | User ID | Start Date | End Date
-----------------------------------------------
RM001       | AD215   | 01/08/2018 | 04/12/2018
-----------------------------------------------
RM001       | AQ110   | 05/12/2018 | 02/04/2019
-----------------------------------------------
RM002       | AD215   | 05/12/2018 | 02/04/2019
```

What I have to show is monthly availability of rooms ( from the 1st Wednesday of the month to the Tuesday before the 1st Wednesday of the next month ) based on the query date to get the following, which details each room, the user and the dates they are using the room :

```
Room Number | 01/08/2018 | 05/09/2018 | 03/10/2018 | 07/11/2018 | 05/12/2018
            | 04/09/2018 | 02/10/2018 | 06/11/2018 | 04/12/2018 | 01/01/2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
RM001       | AD215      | AD215      | AD215      | AD215      | AQ110
            | 01/08/2018 | 01/08/2018 | 01/08/2018 | 01/08/2018 | 05/12/2018
            | 04/12/2018 | 04/12/2018 | 04/12/2018 | 04/12/2018 | 02/04/2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
RM002       | Vacant     | Vacant     | Vacant     | Vacant     | AD215
            |            |            |            |            | 05/12/2018
            |            |            |            |            | 02/04/2019
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've searched on creating custom column headers but there doesn't seem to be a way to create based on the query and using this as part of the query to pull the data.  Nor can I find a way to make the custom headers the 1st Wednesday of the month and the Tuesday before the 1st Wednesday of the next month and using this as part of the query.

I'm able to do this in Excel by using INDEX and MATCH, but it's taking so long to calculate and I'd prefer to find a way to do this at source, so I can run as often as I like.

Has anyone got any guidance on search parameters to use to create such a query or know of a resource that details examples I can learn from please?

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name, I've added sql-server.

Comment: why do you need a date time span as a column name?

Comment: @Simo, to see if that room is in use that month, as rooms are booked from the first Wednesday of the month to the Tuesday before the first Wednesday the following month.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

Your table shows data that exists (e.g. booking for RM001 in 1st August) and data that doesn't (e.g. no booking for RM002 in 1st August). With SQL you would usually select only data that exists. In your case bookings (one result row per room and booked month). It is your app or website that would care about the layout, i.e. put the data in your grid. This is how I would do it.

You *can* turn rows into columns in SQL - provided you know the columns beforehand. If it is always five months you want to show for instance, then this would be possible. You'd use the pivot keyword if available or conditional aggregation for this. With pivot it is possible to create column titles based on your data; with conditional aggregation it is not.

You can even create the 'Vacent' cells in SQL. You would probably select all months and cross join with all rooms. This would give you all your "cells" (i.e. 5 x 2 = 10 rows in your example). You would then outer join your bookings to fill cells with bookings.

Is it possible to have multiple bookings in a month? E.g. AD215 booking th first half, AD216 booking the second half? If so, you must think about how to display this.

You get the first Wednesday of a month by looking at the first day of the month, seeing which day it is and adding zero to six days to get to the first Wednesday.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten.
We'd want the data in a grid to make it easier to read.
We won't know what the column names are - I was hoping it could be done dynamically - so I tell the script to compile data between two dates and it dynamically creates the columns based on that.  So far I get the impression this isn't possible in SQL, from the sites I've already searched, but I wasn't sure. So, sometimes I could do a year, other times half a year.
"Vacant" could just be a gap - just wary of #N/A appearing.
Multiple bookings could be possible but rare.
I'll look at how to get the 1st Wed that way.